# PHP malformed IP address and host. What is this?

Tags: php, ip, ip-address, malformed, gethostbyaddr

I track downloads from my website by adding a database entry for each download that contains the IP address and host of the downloading person.

I use this PHP code to retrieve the IP address

```
isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]) ? $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] : $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]
```

and the host with the PHP function `gethostbyaddr`, passing the IP address.

**This has been working perfectly fine for years**, until something weird happened:

Today I saw two download entries for which both the IP address and host are `2a02:2028:1aa:2dc1:854e:9ccc:b423:7c93`.

[Domaintools](http://whois.domaintools.com/2a02:2028:1aa:2dc1:854e:9ccc:b423:7c93) says it's a "Malformed Domain or IP".

Could someone tell me what that thing is and why it's malformed?

I don't think it's a bot or something because my stuff can only be downloaded by real persons, so I'm really confused?!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address

Comment: The `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` header can be manually changed, `REMOTE_ADDR` cannot.

Comment: Using a proxy or TOR will change REMOTE_ADDR just fine. In this case @OliverCharlesworth is absolutely right. It's simply an IPv6 address and nothing to worrie about.

Comment: You cannot change `REMOTE_ADDR` to whatever you'd like to though? It's always an IP address, `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` can be changed to any string you'd like.

Comment: It should contain an IP address yes. I'm sure there are exceptions to the rule (hacked PHP server), but normally it's safe to assume there's an IP address inside. Doesn't mean you can't change it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's not malformed.
2. It's an [IPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) address.
3. It's probably someone tunnelling or proxying from their IPv6 network into the IPv4 internet.
4. DomainTools doesn't seem to be IPv6 aware, or at least not the tool you used, but [this one is](https://www.ultratools.com/tools/ipv6InfoResult?ipAddress=2a02%3A2028%3A1aa%3A2dc1%3A854e%3A9ccc%3Ab423%3A7c93).